# Moving files from place to place in Rust

Tags: rust, file-move

Say I have a file structure like so

```
a
|
+-- x
|
+-- y
b
```

and I wish to move x from a to b, what would be the best way of achieving this in Rust? I am working on Windows, but would optimally like to add cross platform support.

I am not particularly experienced with Rust at the moment, and haven't been able to find an answer on the web.

**EDIT**
The cross platform support is unimportant at the moment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::fs::rename()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.rename.html) to move a file.